# How to access localstorage by JavaScript which is created by ngStorage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have an AngularJS application which will save something to localstorage by ngStorage ($localstorage). I need to access that data using JavaScript (localstorage.getitem()) from the ajax request data.

I have checked the variable in this situation.

In Angular, I check the $localstorage variable and the result is:

[image]

and the localstorage variable is different :

[image]

I have two questions:

1. whether the variable "ngStorage-token" is just the token stored in angularjs ?
2. obviously they are different, so how is "localstorage" able to access the data stored by "$localstorage"?

Comment: About two rules:
1.ngStorage will sync with localstorae after the script has been finished.
2.the name in localstorage will be "ngStorage-'name'", if you want to access the data saved by ngStorage.

Answer (score 0):

ngStorage module makes Web Storage working in the Angular Way.

`$localStorage` and `$sessionStorage` are the module services, synchronized with and working directly with `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` by saving, retrieving and removing data from them.

Detailed explanation on how to use it can be found [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) .

Comment: the document said "changes will be automatically sync'd between $scope.$storage, $localStorage, and localStorage" . but why the they are different when i check the values ? they even dont have the same key for storage.?

Comment: Because $localStorage is a service of the ngStorage module used to access localStorage and  localStorage is the storage Object of the browser used to store data.

Comment: so in this case , localstorage must contains the value that ngStorage stored. Am I right ? one more is why there is not a value corresponding with the value i stored by ngStorage?

Comment: Yes, and you should provide some code so i can help you further.

Comment: Thanks I have tested, the sync will be doing after the script finished. And if  we stored data using ngStorage, in localstorage there should be one iterm called "ngStorage-'name defined in angularjs'".

Comment: Exactly, also because of that, using the ngStorage service makes the use of localStorage and sessinStorage directly redundant .

Answer (score 0):

When you store a  value in your browser's localStorage using ngStorage like below
Store using ngStorage

```
$localStorage.key = 'value1';
```

To access this value using normal javascript localStorage, You add **ngStorage-key** like below to the name

Get using Javascript

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('ngStorage-key');
```

This is equivalent into

```
storedValue = 'value1';
```

I hope this helps anyone else